# how can I import a ui made in adobe xd to Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, import

my designer partner and I working on an app but she made all in adobe XD and I could not find a way to import her design to Xcode? Do you know if there is a way? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to export any image assets (icons etc) and build the UI yourself in Xcode. There's no way to import design files.